# Concurrent insert of keys into a table

Tags: sql, delphi, concurrency, firebird, auto-increment

Probably a trivial question, but I want to get the best possible solution.

Problem:

I have two or more workers that insert keys into one or more tables. The problem arises when two or more workers try to insert the same key into one of those key tables at the same time.
Typical problem.

1. Worker A reads the table if a key exists (SELECT). There is no key.
2. Worker B reads the table if a key exists (SELECT). There is no key.
3. Worker A inserts the key.
4. Worker B inserts the key.
5. Worker A commits.
6. Worker B commits. Exception is throws as unique constraint is violated

The key tables are simple pairs. First column is autoincrement integer and the second is varchar key.

What is the best solution to such a concurrency problem? I believe it is a common problem. One way for sure is to handle the exceptions thrown, but somehow I don't believe this is the best way to tackle this.

The database I use is Firebird 2.5

**EDIT**:

Some additional info to make things clear.

1. Client side synchronization is not a good approach, because the inserts come from different processes (workers). And I could have workers across different machines someday, so even mutexes are a no-go.
2. The primary key and the first columns of such a table is autoincrement field. No problem there. The varchar field is the problem as it is something that the client inserts.

Typical such table is a table of users. For instance:

```
1  2056
2  1044
3  1896
4  5966
...
```

Each worker check if user "xxxx" exists and if not inserts it.

**EDIT 2**:

Just for the reference if somebody will go the same route. IB/FB return pair of error codes (I am using InterBase Express components). Checking for duplicate value violation look like this:

```
except
  on E: EIBInterBaseError do
  begin
    if (E.SQLCode = -803) and (E.IBErrorCode = 335544349) then
    begin
      FKeysConnection.IBT.Rollback;
      EnteredKeys := False;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Reading the answers I just got an idea. I could have another worker whose only purpose would be to insert key data. Other workers would send the data to it via IPC or TCP. Seems a good solution and also works across multiple computers. Still I want to see what you guys come up with.

Comment: So a user is trying to insert a duplicate value of a key which is constrained to be unique. They will get an error and that's how it should be. What's the problem?

Comment: This are automated workers, there is no user behind them. The data comes from a large "logging" table upon which the workers operate. They make some kind of reports. Maybe it is the right thing to do to try to repeat the select / insert if exception occurs. I am just trying to get all possible views solutions on the matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Firebird you can use the following statement:

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (MY_KEY) VALUES (:MY_KEY) MATCHING (MY_KEY) RETURNING MY_ID
```

- assuming there is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger which will generate the MY_ID if a NULL value is being inserted.

Here is the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-update-or-insert.html).

**Update**: The above statement will avoid exceptions and cause every statement to succeed. However, in case of many duplicate key values it will also cause many unnecessary updates.
This can be avoided by another approach: just handle the unique constraint exception on the client and ignore it. The details depend on which Delphi library you're using to work with Firebird but it should be possible to examine the SQLCode returned by the server and ignore only the specific case of unique constraint violation.

Comment: Making sure threads don't work on the same record is better: What happens if you have 10 threads, they all select the first Key, solve the problem, then run this query: They all succeed. Then they ALL select the next available record, and they all work on that same record again, repeating until all work is done. You end up doing all work 10 times, not doing work 10 times faster.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: I thought the goal was that they all succeed, ie. to make sure the record exists with the correct key value. To "make sure the threads don't work on the same record" IMHO doesn't work (they may be running on different computers).

Comment: The goal is to ensure that all different keys are inserted only once into the key table. Different workers may try to insert the same key. For instance a user id (which is a string). It is a logging system that logs different APIs. Workers then make report data tables out of the raw data recorded. And a events worker may try to insert a user to the keys table and also the case data worker tries to do the same. They both have users as part of their internal report data. Before of joins I want all string data to be numerical and have key tables for descriptions. This is why all this is done :)

Comment: And I cannot know all possible keys up front. I generate them on the fly. This is why it gets complicated.

Comment: Perhaps all you need to do is handle the unique constraint exception on the client by just ignoring it?

Comment: Yes this is certainly one of the options. I was hoping to avoid handling things with exceptions because I don't like it, but it seems to be the appropriate solution here. More so because the frequency of such collisions is low.

Comment: Yes, that's how it seems to me.

Comment: Please update your answer with exception handling option and I will accept it. I cannot accept the current one because it would be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if something like this is avalible in Firebird but in SQL Server you can check when inserting the key.

```
insert into Table1 (KeyValue) 
select 'NewKey'
where not exists (select *
                  from Table1
                  where KeyValue = 'NewKey')
```

Comment: Won't there still be a problem if two such statements are executed at the same time, before each of the workers make a commit. Statement B would not see that Statement A just inserted something because of the transaction isolation. Am I wrong? Otherwise Firebird supports a similar statement.

Comment: I can't answer for sure what Firebird will do but in SQL Server this is treated like one statement and there will be a lock on the table so that no one can add rows at the exact same time. Without that, the auto incremented id would not work either.

Comment: What will happen if two threads try to insert the same key at the same time is that one will successfully add one new line and the other will not add a new line. The only difference is that the first one will have `(1 row(s) affected)` and the seconds will have `(0 row(s) affected)`.

Answer (score 2):

### First option - don't do it.

Don't do it; Unless the WORKERS are doing extraordinary amounts of work (we're talking about computers, so requiring 1 second per record qualifies as "extraordinary amount of work"), just use a single thread; Even better, do all the work in a stored procedure, you'd be amazed by the speedup gained by not transporting data over whatever protocol into your app.

### Second option - Use a Queue

Make sure your worker threads don't all work on the same ID. Set up a Queue, push all the ID's that need processing into that queue, have each working thread Dequeue an ID from that Queue. This way you're guaranteed no two workers work on the same record at the same time. This might be difficult to implement if your workers are not all part of the same process.

### Last resort

Set up an DB-based "Reservation" system so an Worker Thread can mark a Key for "work in process" so no two workers would work on the same Key. I'd set up a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE KEY_RESERVATIONS (
  KEY INTEGER NOT NULL, /* This is the KEY you'd be reserving */
  RESERVED_UNTIL TIMESTAMP NOT NULL /* We don't want to keep reservations for ever in case of failure */
);
```

Each of your workers would use short transactions to work on that table: Select a candidate Key, one that's not in the KEY_RESERVATIONS table. Try to INSERT. Failed? Try an other KEY. Periodically delete all reserved key with old RESERVED_UNTIL timestamps. Make sure the transactions for working with KEY_RESERVATIONS are as short as possible, so that two threads both trying to reserve the same key at the same time would fail quickly.

Comment: It is not a reservation issue. The keys are inserted, when a key is used that is not yet in the table. Maybe the word key was the confusion here. I did not chose that well. The problem is when two or more workers try to insert the same "key" (string description for an ID).

Answer (score 1):

This is what you have to deal with in an optimistic (or no-) locking scheme.

One way to avoid it is to put a pessimistic lock on the table around the whole select, insert, commit sequence.

However, that means you will have to deal with not being able to access the table (handle table-locked exceptions).

If by workers you mean threads in the same application instance instead of different users (application instances), you will need thread synchronization like kubal5003 says around the select-insert-commit sequence.

A combination of the two is needed if you have multiple users/application instances each with multiple threads.

Comment: Yes I have multiple processes. Mutex solves such a problem, but I was hoping for a DB side solution. Locking does not look good to me :) Queries need those key tables.

Comment: Mutexes are fine in that case, unless the processes are on different machines. IIRC mutexes don't work across machines, at least not "out-of-the-box". Depending on your server (and I am not that familiar with Firebird), you can (should be able) to lock for write while allowing reads, sort of like the SHARE_DENY_WRITE file locking.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize your threads to make it impossible to insert the same value or use a db side key generation method (I don't know Firebird so I don't even know if it's there, eg. in MsSQL Server there is identity column or GUIDs also solve the problem because it's unlikely to generate two identical ones)

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it more clear how the setup is done

Answer (score 0):

You should not rely the client to generate the unique key, if there's possibility for duplicates.

Use triggers and generators (maybe with help of stored procedure) to create always unique keys.

More information about proper autoinc implementation in Firebird here: http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/

Comment: You have not understood my problem correctly. I have key tables so that in my main data tables I only operate with integer values. For instance I have users key table where I have different users stored. In my main data tables I only operate with users as integers and then join their usernames from the key table. I already use autoinrement and stored procedures. The problem is that two workers that operate on two different data tables both want to update the users key table with the same user. This has nothing to do with autoinrement.